# why isnt my media query doing anything?

Tags: html, css, media

I'm not sure why the follow CSS code isn't doing anything, it was working I did some changes it was a good bit I don't really call all what I changed, but then now its just staying on what's supposed to be the mobile version. I also tried adding "screen" and "all", nothing.

Running it in updated Google Chrome and also tried Edge.

```css
/*
 MEDIA QUERIES
*/
@media (min-width: 615px) {
 
 header h1 {
  transform: scale(1,1);
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 5%;
 }
 
 .main-container img {
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 0;
 }
 
 .mobileRef {
  display:none;
 }
 
 nav a {
  font-size: 18px;
 }

 nav li {
  padding: 0 1.5%;
 }
 
 nav {
  text-align: right;
 }

 header p {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  margin: 12px 5% 0 0;
 }
 
 
 .break {
  display: none;
 }
 
)
```

Comment: you're viewing on window/viewport smaller than 615px right? had to ask since youre using min-width

Comment: This media query css will show when screen size more than `615px`. https://jsfiddle.net/hf3p98h7/

Answer (score 3):

Change your end bracket on your query. Should be }, not )

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 615px) {
  .class
  {
  .myclass:value; 
  }
}
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.